# How to generate a matrix using the memory of a non-contiguous views of an existed matrix in Armadillo?

Tags: subview, armadillo

Currently I can generate a matrix using same memory of **contiguous views** of an existed matrix, so that a subview of the existed matrix can be changed efficiently.
that can be done as follows

```
mat mat1(4,4,fill::zeros);
double *auxmem = mat1.memptr();
mat sub1 = mat(auxmem[startIndex], n_rows, n_cols, false, false);
```

but for the non-contiguous views, it can not be done like that.
After reading the head file about subview and subview_elem2, I found out an other way to complete it.

```
subview_elem2<unsigned, umat, umat> sub1 = mat1.submat(v, v);//non-contiguous index
subview<unsigned> sub2 = mat2.submat(1, 1, 2, 2);            //contiguous index
```

Changing `sub1` can effect to `mat1`, and changing `sub2` can effect to `mat2`, it seems like a better way to reach the goal.

But the `sub1` and `sub2` are not the type of `Mat<double>`, lots of operations cannot be done on them. Is there any decent way to generate a non-contiguous subview with same memory? Thank you.